# Display options for formatting text like microsoft word in php/codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

[How to create in php or codeigniter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iyy4y.png)
convert rich text to html format

Comment: use this texteditor: http://ckeditor.com/

Comment: It's free or paid

Comment: it is free.. you can use.

Answer (score 1):

You should not ask the question this way.
First go to [https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SSAQK4Nwkm4]

and have basic understanding of what rich text is in the web. then search for wyswyg editor, integrate it with your textarea and make the target field in the database table longtext datatype.